# Showing that a set is uncountable from an injective map

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Consider the space $\mathbb R^{\mathbb R}$ of all functions $f : \mathbb R → \mathbb R$.

Let $f_1, f_2, . . .$ be a sequence of functions $\mathbb R → \mathbb R$ in the product topology to a function $f : \mathbb R → \mathbb R$.

Show that for every $ε > 0$, there exists a number $n_0$ such that the set

{$x ∈ \mathbb R : |f(x) − f_n(x)| < ε$ for all $n ≥ n_0$} is uncountable.

> I know that if I want to show that a set $X$ is uncountable, then it is enough to show that there exists an injective map: $Y → X$ from a set $Y$ which we already know is uncountable. In particular, Y could be the interval $(0,1)$.
> So if want to define $h: (0,1) → X$, where $X :=$ {$x ∈ \mathbb R : |f(x) − f_n(x)| < ε$ for all $n ≥ n_0$}, how can I show that $h$ is injective?

Comment: Are you assuming that $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ for every $x$?

Comment: Yes, and in fact this is what my set $X$ is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that $f_n \to f$ pointwise exactly means

$$\forall x \in \Bbb R: \forall \varepsilon>0: \exists N:=N(x,\varepsilon): \forall n \ge N: |f_n(x)-f(x)| < \varepsilon\tag{1}$$

So if we define (your set of interest)

$$T(\varepsilon, n_0):= \{x \in \Bbb R\mid \forall n \ge n_0: |f_n(x)-f(x)|< \varepsilon\}$$

$(1)$ can be restated as:

$$\forall \varepsilon>0 : \Bbb R = \bigcup_{n \in \Bbb N} T(\varepsilon, n)\tag{2}$$

(given $\varepsilon>0$, for $x \in R$ we know that $x \in T(\varepsilon, N(x,\varepsilon))$ and so in the union, the reverse inclusion is always trivial).

So for every $\varepsilon>0$ one of these sets $T(\varepsilon, n)$ must be *uncountable* (or else $\Bbb R$ would be a countable union of *countable* sets and thus countable, contradiction!). This is exactly your statement.

Answer (score 2):

We are dealing with the product topology and so convergence is the pointwise convergence. So $f_n\to f$ if and only if $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Fix $\epsilon >0$. Then for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$ there is a natural number $N(x)$ such that for any $n>N(x)$ we have $|f_{n}(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$. And so we have a function $N:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{N}$. Since $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable and $\mathbb{N}$ is countable, then there is $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $N^{-1}(n_0)$ is uncountable (otherwise $\mathbb{R}$ would be a countable union of countable subsets, which cannot happen).

Can you verify that this $n_0$ is what we are looking for?

Comment: How does this tell me that thebset is uncountable?

Comment: @JOJO $N^{-1}(n_0)$ is your subset.